# Rolling fixed window scheme for GARCH forecasting

Tags: time-series, garch, volatility-forecasting, rolling-window

I'm working on my bachelors thesis which mainly revolves around this paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2225-1146/4/1/3/htm

Shortly after describing the dataset in 3.1 the authors mention that they use a rolling fixed window scheme to estimate the parameters and to predict the conditional variance for the next 20 days. The time windows and forecast horizons are listed in a table in the appendix.

I get what they did and I understand the reasoning behind it, but I can't find any literature about it. Why did they decide to chose 20 days? Why not 10 or 50? Is there any rule I should follow if I want to incorporate this method myself, considering I use a different dataset and timescale?

As of now, I estimated the parameters for my in-sample and then forecasted the variance for the out-sample using this parameter. Would that be wrong?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forecast horizon should normally depend on the application. If the model is considered in a context where agents are looking 20 days ahead and making decisions based on a 20-day outlook, 20-day ahead forecasts is what is needed. If the model is analyzed without a particular application in mind, one could look at multiple forecast horizons and analyze all of them. Of course, that would be more work.

What is sensible in your case also depends on the application. There is likely nothing wrong with using a 20-day horizon, but this horizon may or may not be relevant and interesting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can accept the answer by clicking on the tick, I didn't know that. Regarding your answer, do you know any literature that explains rolling fixed windows mathematically? I've looked through my textbooks on time series but haven't found anything unfortunately.

Comment: @crevez, which aspects of rolling windows are you interested in? The construction of rolling windows is pretty simple. The use is based on the general idea of cross validation combined with the fact that time series observations are not independent.

Comment: I was thinking about using a rolling window in my bachelors thesis, which is why I wanted to know a mathematical description of it so that I can mention it briefly in my thesis. But I just decided against that, since I don't think it will add any value to the analysis I actually focus on. Still, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @crevez, you are welcome!